# Redirect url to app excludes parameters when browser is initiated in App

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-linking

Trying to set up an authentication flow  that runs in browser for a mobile app but the token url parameters in my app redirect(eg: `exp://192.168.29.4:8081?token=<something>`) go missing .

A minimal reproducible example of my issue can be made by creating an app redirect with a token parameter on the backend as (using express to demonstrate):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect(302, 'exp://192.168.29.4:8081?token=something');
});

app.listen(3000, () => {});
```

and log the url parameters on the client side as

```
import * as Linking from "expo-linking";
...
const url = Linking.useURL();

  if (url) {
    console.log(url)
    const { hostname, path, queryParams } = Linking.parse(url);
    console.log(
      `Linked to app with hostname: ${hostname}, path: ${path} and data: ${JSON.stringify(queryParams)}`);
  }
```

If I open `localhost:3000` on safari in the ios simulator, I am redirected to the app with the token parameter logged as expected. But If I use expo-linking or expo-web-browser as:

```
import * as Linking from "expo-linking";
...
Linking.openURL('http://127.0.0.1:3000')
```

or

```
import * as WebBrowser from "expo-web-browser";
...
await WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync('http://127.0.0.1:3000')
```

I am redirected to the app but the parameters are logged as empty.

How can I open the auth flow using `Linking` or `WebBrowser` and ensure that the app redirect contains the token parameters